# how to append dynamic div permanently using html, javascript, jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'd like to append dynamic div using Jquery as

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#add_item").on('click',function(){ 
             if(i < max)
            { 
            var szData = ""; 
            var $OthersEX = '$Others'+j+'EX'; 
            var $OthersGD = '$Others'+j+'GD'; 
            var $OthersFA = '$Others'+j+'FA'; 
            var $OthersPR = '$Others'+j+'PR'; 
            if (i==1) 
            {
                <?php $OthersEX=$Others1EX; $OthersGD=$Others1GD; $OthersFA=$Others1FA; $OthersPR=$Others1PR; $errorOthers=$errorOthers1; ?>
            } 
            szData = '<div class="services-item"><div class="form-group"><div class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            <input type="checkbox" name="item_index[]" /><select id="sel_box" name="sel_services[]"><option value="Facilities">Facilities</option>
            <option value="Housekeeping">Housekeeping</option><option value="Security">Security</option><option value="Cafeteria">Cafeteria</option>
            <option value="Florist">Florist</option><option value="Delifrance">Delifrance</option><option value="Pharmacy">Pharmacy</option>
            <option value="Parentcraft">Parentcraft Retail</option><option value="Car">Car Park</option></select></div>';           
            szData = szData + '<label class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">Please rate your experience.</label>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12"><label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="care[' + j +']" value="Excellent" <?php echo $OthersEX; ?> >Excellent</label>
            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="care[' + j +']" value="Good" <?php echo $OthersGD; ?> >Good</label><label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="care[' + j +']" value="Fair" <?php echo $OthersFA; ?> >Fair</label>
            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="care[' + j +']" value="Poor" <?php echo $OthersPR; ?> >Poor</label><?php echo $errorOthers; ?></div></div><div class="form-group"><label class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">Areas we do well / Areas needing improvement:</label>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12"><textarea class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" id="comment" rows="5" ></textarea></div></div></div>';
            $("#services").append(szData); 
            j++;i++;            
            } 
    }); 
    });
```

Based on button click, it append as div services-item inside div services. I did error check with variable $errorOthers that prompt error message to make the form fields to make mandatory. When click submit button and if there is error message in form, form is shown with specific error message to user. But at that time, dynamically added div is disappeared. May I know how to append div dynamically and permanently. That is not to disappear and show existing/ appending div/form in obliterated UI when click submit button.

Comment: Hi freedomn-m, i need to POST a full page as there are the rest fields check to input by user as mandatory fileds

Comment: may I know how to make ajax post. I guess ajax will happen same.